# Read the windows log files using C++ and WMI(Windows Management Instrumentation)

Tags: c++, wmi

I have been going through the windows docs to access the windows log files using C++ and WMI. I saw a sample code for creating a WMI application. But it shows an error when I compile it using the g++ compiler.

code:

```
#define _WIN32_DCOM
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Wbemidl.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    HRESULT hres;

// Initialize COM.
hres =  CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); 
if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Failed to initialize COM library. " 
        << "Error code = 0x" 
        << hex << hres << endl;
    return 1;              // Program has failed.
}

// Initialize 
hres =  CoInitializeSecurity(
    NULL,     
    -1,      // COM negotiates service                  
    NULL,    // Authentication services
    NULL,    // Reserved
    RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,    // authentication
    RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,  // Impersonation
    NULL,             // Authentication info 
    EOAC_NONE,        // Additional capabilities
    NULL              // Reserved
    );


if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Failed to initialize security. " 
        << "Error code = 0x" 
        << hex << hres << endl;
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;          // Program has failed.
}

// Obtain the initial locator to Windows Management
// on a particular host computer.
IWbemLocator *pLoc = 0;

hres = CoCreateInstance(
    CLSID_WbemLocator,             
    0, 
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
    IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &amp;pLoc);

if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Failed to create IWbemLocator object. "
        << "Error code = 0x"
        << hex << hres << endl;
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;       // Program has failed.
}

IWbemServices *pSvc = 0;

// Connect to the root\cimv2 namespace with the
// current user and obtain pointer pSvc
// to make IWbemServices calls.

hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(

    _bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), // WMI namespace
    NULL,                    // User name
    NULL,                    // User password
    0,                       // Locale
    NULL,                    // Security flags                 
    0,                       // Authority       
    0,                       // Context object
    &amp;pSvc                    // IWbemServices proxy
    );                              

if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Could not connect. Error code = 0x" 
        << hex << hres << endl;
    pLoc->Release();     
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;                // Program has failed.
}

cout << "Connected to ROOT\\CIMV2 WMI namespace" << endl;

// Set the IWbemServices proxy so that impersonation
// of the user (client) occurs.
hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(

   pSvc,                         // the proxy to set
   RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,            // authentication service
   RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,             // authorization service
   NULL,                         // Server principal name
   RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,       // authentication level
   RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,  // impersonation level
   NULL,                         // client identity 
   EOAC_NONE                     // proxy capabilities     
);

if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Could not set proxy blanket. Error code = 0x" 
         << hex << hres << endl;
    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();     
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;               // Program has failed.
}


// Use the IWbemServices pointer to make requests of WMI. 
// Make requests here:

// For example, query for all the running processes
IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
    bstr_t("WQL"), 
    bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process"),
    WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
    NULL,
    &amp;pEnumerator);

if (FAILED(hres))
{
    cout << "Query for processes failed. "
         << "Error code = 0x" 
         << hex << hres << endl;
    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();     
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;               // Program has failed.
}
else
{ 
    IWbemClassObject *pclsObj;
    ULONG uReturn = 0;

    while (pEnumerator)
    {
        hres = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, 
            &amp;pclsObj, &amp;uReturn);

        if(0 == uReturn)
        {
            break;
        }

        VARIANT vtProp;

        // Get the value of the Name property
        hres = pclsObj->Get(L"Name", 0, &amp;vtProp, 0, 0);
        wcout << "Process Name : " << vtProp.bstrVal << endl;
        VariantClear(&amp;vtProp);

        pclsObj->Release();
        pclsObj = NULL;
    }

}

// Cleanup
// ========

pSvc->Release();
pLoc->Release();
pEnumerator->Release();  

CoUninitialize();

return 0;   // Program successfully completed.
}
```

If I saved it in a file named sample.cpp I compiled it suing the command

```
 g++ -o sample sample.cpp
```

Is that a mistake? Should I be compiling it in a different way?

I'm new to this. Can somebody please guide me on how to learn the WMI using C++ in order to read the windows log files?

Kindly respond

Thank you.

Comment: What is the error you're seeing?

Comment: 1-[ Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) E0020 identifier "amp" is undefined Project1 c:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\Project1\Source.cpp 59 ]

2- [ Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) E0018 expected a ')' Project1 c:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\Project1\Source.cpp 59 ]

These are a few. I tried it in Visual Studio. But still it shows the same error. What is the datatype of amp if it is to be declared and why is there a semicolon before all the parameters? 

Thank you for the response.

Comment: It would be great if someone could help me get access a log file at least from a local machine. I can't really figure out what the error is about. Kindly help.

Comment: `&amp;` is actually HTML encoding for the `&` character, which is highly unusual in source code. I suspect that this was unintentional and likely resulted from a copy/paste from a webpage or other example code. In your code, you should replace `&amp;` with `&`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was right. I could get the output. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have just copy pasted the code from a website, due to which `&` has become `&amp;` (because of HTML) as mentioned in the comments by @Vlad274.

If you're compiling in the command prompt, you have to link your libraries before compilation, probably `ole32` and `oleaut`.

If you're using Visual Studio, make sure they are included in the linker settings.(Which they are by default in VS2017)

EXTRA: Before using the `Get` method, you could check for property names using the `GetNames` method to ensure that the property 'Name' exists.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks a lot for the help.